# Selenium Grid, Vagrant, unable to run tests from Eclipse

Tags: selenium, grid, vagrant, virtualbox

I am attempting to automate our testing using Selenium and Selenium Grid 2. To do this I have create a VirtualBox VM and packaged it with vagrant into a box. Using simple batch scripts, eventually want to run this on a Jenkins CI server, I can start the vagrant box,but I get:

```
    c:\seleniumServer>vagrant up
    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Importing base box 'IE_Vagrant.box'...
    ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
    ==> default: Setting the name of the  VM:seleniumServer_default_1436811491763_573
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
    ==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: password
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

    If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
    the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I can start the Selenium Hub, and selenium Node and they register. I can even ssh into the vagrant box after it is done telling it it cannot connect. I have setup cygwin and OpenSSH on the box.

When I try to run the testNg test from Eclipse I get :

> Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to 10.0.2.15:5566 [/10.0.2.15] failed: Connection timed out: connect.

Here are the relevant bits.

Start node with

```
java -jar lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="chrome",version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=5 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="c\seleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe"
```

Start the Hub with

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role hub
```

VagrantFile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.boot_timeout = "300"
config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
config.vm.network "public_network"
config.vm.box = "IE_Vagrant.box"
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
 # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
vb.gui = true
 #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
 #   vb.memory = "1024"
end
```

And here is my test:

```
package com.hiiq.qa.testing.gen2;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GridTest {
   private static RemoteWebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
    capability.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.chrome().getBrowserName());
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    //capability.setVersion("");
    capability.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.70.1.28:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
    driver.get("http://10.1.6.112:8383");
}

@Test
public void loginTest(){
```

Comment: Do you have properly installed the virtualbox guestadditions inside the vagrant box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this tutorial if the box is properly setup, especially virtualbox guest additions: https://dennypc.wordpress.com/2014/06/09/creating-a-windows-box-with-vagrant-1-6/

vagrant up and vagrant ssh should work properly.

Then setup your Vagrantfile for Port Forwarding:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.boot_timeout = "300"
  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.box = "IE_Vagrant.box"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4444, host: 4444
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8383, host: 8383
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    vb.gui = true
    #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
    #   vb.memory = "1024"
  end
end
```

Contact your services in your tests by localhost:4444 and localhost:8383.

Comment: Well that got rid of the connection time outs, thanks for that. and indeed vagrant ssh does work. I just wish I remember how to use ViM heh. When I run my test against the hub though I am still getting: FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to 10.0.2.15:5555 [/10.0.2.15] failed: Connection timed out: connect
Command duration or timeout: 81.98 seconds

Comment: Still missing a port,see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2: Nodes default port is 5555.

Comment: According to this tutorial https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2. You first start the hub then the node. You do it the other way around. Then properly set where Selenium should contact the hub: Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(“localhost”, 4444, “*firefox”, “http://www.google.com”); and then properly configure your remote driver:  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability); and get rid of this: driver.get("http://10.1.6.112:8383");